# Powershell: Count items in a folder with PowerShell

Tags: powershell-2.0

I'm trying to write a very simple PowerShell script to give me the total number of items (both files and folders) in a given folder (`c:\MyFolder`).  Here's what I've done:

```
Write-Host ( Get-ChildItem c:\MyFolder ).Count;
```

The problem is, that if I have 1 or 0 items, the command does not work---it returns nothing.

Any ideas?

Comment: This is really old, so here's the quick answer for the old problem:  Change your command to `Write-Host @( Get-ChildItem c:\MyFolder ).Count;`. This keeps older versions of Powershell from collapsing/unwrapping the list/array returned by `Get-ChildItem` when there's less than 2 elements in it.

Answer (score 203, accepted):

You should use `Measure-Object` to count things. In this case it would look like:

```
Write-Host ( Get-ChildItem c:\MyFolder | Measure-Object ).Count;
```

or if that's too long

```
Write-Host ( dir c:\MyFolder | measure).Count;
```

and in PowerShell 4.0 use the `measure` alias instead of `mo`

```
Write-Host (dir c:\MyFolder | measure).Count;
```

Comment: How to get count for all folders inside a particular folder?

Comment: THis `Write-Host ( Get-ChildItem c:\MyFolder | Measure-Object ).Count` worked for me

Comment: The `measure` alias *replaces* `mo` *starting from* PowerShell 4.0

Answer (score 50):

If you need to speed up the process (for example counting 30k or more files) then I would go with something like this..

```
$filepath = "c:\MyFolder"
$filetype = "*.txt"
$file_count = [System.IO.Directory]::GetFiles("$filepath", "$filetype").Count
```

Comment: That is an order of magnitude faster! Thanks. I had a folder with over 29K files in it, and this method returned the count as fast as my finger lifted from the RETURN key.

Comment: You can recurse this with `[System.IO.Directory]::GetFiles("$filepath", "$filetype",1)` See [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.directory.getfiles?view=netframework-4.8)

Comment: Or filter with regex with 
`$r = <regex>` and `(Get-ChildItem) -match $r | Select FullName, @{name = "FileCount"; expression = {[System.IO.Directory]::GetFiles($_).Count}}`

Answer (score 46):

I finally found this link:

https://blogs.perficient.com/microsoft/2011/06/powershell-count-property-returns-nothing/

> Well, it turns out that this is a quirk caused precisely because there
>   was only one file in the directory. Some searching revealed that in
>   this case, PowerShell returns a scalar object instead of an array.
>   This object doesn’t have a count property, so there isn’t anything to
>   retrieve.

The solution -- force PowerShell to return an array with the `@` symbol:

```
Write-Host @( Get-ChildItem c:\MyFolder ).Count;
```

Comment: Perfect, thanks.  I find it annoying when commandlets try and be "helpful" and vary their return type.

Answer (score 19):

Only Files

```
Get-ChildItem D:\ -Recurse -File | Measure-Object | %{$_.Count}
```

Only Folders

```
Get-ChildItem D:\ -Recurse -Directory | Measure-Object | %{$_.Count}
```

Both

```
Get-ChildItem D:\ -Recurse | Measure-Object | %{$_.Count}
```

Comment: On the first one, how would I search for all jpg and png files?

Comment: @AlLelopath ``Get-ChildItem D:\ -Recurse -File -Include *.jpg,*.png | Measure-Object | %{$_.Count}``

Comment: hi @dhcgn any advice on this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54916917/powershell-script-to-count-files-only-excluding-folders

Answer (score 9):

You can also use an alias

```
(ls).Count
```

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for

Answer (score 3):

Recursively count files in directories in PowerShell 2.0

```
ls -rec | ? {$_.mode -match 'd'} | select FullName,  @{N='Count';E={(ls $_.FullName | measure).Count}}
```

Answer (score 1):

In powershell you can to use severals commands, for looking for this commands digit: `Get-Alias`;

So the cammands the can to use are:

```
write-host (ls MydirectoryName).Count
```

or

```
write-host (dir MydirectoryName).Count
```

or

```
write-host (Get-ChildrenItem MydirectoryName).Count
```

Answer (score 0):

To count the number of a specific filetype in a folder. 
The example is to count mp3 files on F: drive.

```
( Get-ChildItme F: -Filter *.mp3 - Recurse | measure ).Count
```

Tested in 6.2.3, but should work >4.