# Recursively count filtered files in subfolders and group results

Tags: windows, powershell, directory-structure

I want to count all files with a particular prefix in a directory and then display the results based on each sub directory.

The directory tree is as follows

```
Test
  January
     sms20180101_110.unl
     rec20180101_110.unl
     data20180101_110.unl
  February
     sms20180201_110.unl
     rec20180201_110.unl
     data20180201_110.unl
  March
    sms20180301_110.unl
    rec20180301_110.unl
    data20180301_110.unl
```

So, I need to count for example the total data files in each subdirectory and display results as follows

```
January      1
February     5
March        10
```

I wrote the following command in Powershell

```
Get-ChildItem -Path D:\Test -Filter *data* -Force -Recurse | Measure-Object | %{$_.Count}
```

So, the problem is it is giving me the total files in the root directory

A similar question was asked here [Recursively count files in subfolders](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25506599/recursively-count-files-in-subfolders) but I have not been able to customize the solutions provided here to my need

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your scenario, you can use `Group-Object` like this -

```
Get-ChildItem -Path D:\Test -Filter *data* -Force -Recurse | Group-Object -Property Directory | Select-Object Name, Count
```

This will list all the name of the folders and sub-folders along with the count of files having **data** in it's name.

Comment: Works like a charm. Thanks

Comment: @db100 - Please consider accepting the answer if it addressed your query.

Comment: As you are not interested in the content of the Group property you could add `-NoElement` to the `Group-Object` this will avoid some overhead. While this is a question of personal preference I'd insert a line break after the pipe symbols and indent to not have these overlong commands forcing to scroll sideways. Otherwise +1