# Recursively count files in subfolders - Follow up question

Tags: powershell

In [recursively-count-files-in-subfolders](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25506599/recursively-count-files-in-subfolders/25507002#25507002) a great working piece of PowerShell code writes to the screen. David comments later that you can redirect to file, but I can't get that to work. I have tried to place it in all kind of different places, but I keep ending up with output writing to screen and an empty file being created.

This is the syntax I would think would work:

```
dir -recurse |  ?{ $_.PSIsContainer } | %{ Write-Host $_.FullName (dir $_.FullName | Measure-Object).Count } | Out-File -FilePath FileCount.txt
```

It is probably super-simple, but for some reason, the logic behind PowerShell syntax keeps eluding me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't use `Write-Host` in that spot.  It will not send information down the pipeline to `Out-File`.

Example:

```
Get-ChildItem -recurse |  
Where-Object{ $_.PSIsContainer } | 
ForEach-Object{ ( $_.FullName + " " + (Get-ChildItem $_.FullName | Measure-Object).Count ) } | 
Out-File -FilePath FileCount.txt
```

[About_Redirection](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_redirection?view=powershell-7) .

What you are really looking for is `Write-Output`, but that is implied in the example.  Above assumes a space as the separator between the path and the count.

An aside: you can use `Get-ChildItem -Directory` instead of `Where-Object{ $_.PSIsContainer }`

A more concise example:

```
Get-ChildItem -Recurse -Directory |  
ForEach-Object{ ( $_.FullName + " " + (Get-ChildItem $_.FullName).Count ) } | 
Out-File -FilePath FileCount.txt
```

Here I use the `-Directory` parameter on `Get-ChildItem` (Dir) instead of the `Where-Object{ $_.PSIsContainer }` and the `.Count` property instead of `Measure-Object`.

Answer (score 0):

Modify `Write-Host` to `Write-Output` and you're there with you're required output in the file!

Comment: I cited `Write-Output` in my previous answer.  However, there's no reason to actually use it and it is atypical to do so.  Unless otherwise consumed everything PowerShell emits is output written to the pipeline.

Comment: Thank you Spandana